# Powershell: List Values of text file as a list

Tags: list, powershell

I am trying to list the values within a text file. I tried

```
Get-Content a.txt
```

and the list works fine.  But when I output it to an email string (Send-MailMessage) the list is not coming up correct.  So it would look like this (like a sentence, one file after the other):

1 2 3 4 5

instead of something like this (a list).

1

2

3

4

5

Do I need to do something different to get the list display properly in the Send-MailMessage as a list rather than a sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: when you display an array `"$array"` it "stringifies" the collection. try this >>> `$Test = @(1, 2, 3, 4); "$Test"` <<< the output will be a one-line string.

Comment: came up as:  1 2 3 4

if you use powershell, it does come up as a list.

Comment: i presume there is supposed to be a full stop before the `if you use`. [*grin*] that is exactly what i said ... you need to _remove the double quotes around the $Var_ to avoid the automatic `.ToString()` call. somewhere in your code you have almost certainly triggered the stringification of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the content in a html email, just join the lines with a `<br>`

```
(Get-Content a.txt) -join '<br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the -raw option.  It will output one string instead of a string array.

```
Get-Content -raw a.txt
```

Comment: even with the -raw command, it still list as a string array.

Comment: What is the actual send-mailmessage command you're running?

Comment: `$Attachment1 = select-string -Path ".\*.ctx" -Pattern $keyword1 -List | select path
$change1 = select-string -path $Attachment1.path -Pattern ".csv" | select line
`
within the body of the email string its HTML

Comment: `<html>
<body>
<br>$change1
</body>
</html>`

Comment: -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml

Comment: I was asking about send-mailmessage.  Can you show the complete code in your question?

Comment: `Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment1.Path`